# color mapping of point cloud based on coordinate values

Tags: matlab, interpolation, point-clouds, colormap

I have a point cloud of the face and I have the thickness of skin defined at 17 points on the face. Based on the thickness defined at 17 points I need to calculate the thickness at other points and have a color map based on the thickness. I have tried different methods  but I have failed badly as I am a beginner in MATLAB. Kindly suggest me something for this problem.

```
clc;
close all;
fid = fopen('cloud.txt');
pointArray = textscan(fid,'%f');
coord = reshape(pointArray{1}, 3 ,size( pointArray{1}, 1 ) / 3);
%% The fourth column of scalars_erect represent the thickness where as the initial 3 colunms are the coordinates of points on the face.
scalars_erect=[-10.81   -70.79  25.95   3.769230769
    -8.97   -61.18  -49.4   9.307692308
    -7.87   -60.07  -96.19  3.076923077
    -70.3   -45.23  -5.278  5.846153846
    -59.93  -56.14  -40.77  10
    -47.51  -63.61  -46.13  7
    -42.78  -64.82  -50.99  4
    -45.1   -51.71  -81.41  1
    -58.19  -47.7   -69.69  4.692307692
    -75.71  -29.2   -54.05  5.384615385
    32.64   -42.04  -5.64   5.846153846
    22.79   -54.73  -41.55  5.153846154
    22.07   -54.84  -44.82  3.538461538
    15.13   -59.8   -51.6   2.615384615
    13.18   -49.52  -87.39  3.769230769
    28.62   -39.47  -71.34  6.076923077
    39.11   -26.79  -52.06  4.230769231
    ];
interpolatedScalars = interpolateScalars( scalars_erect, coord');
interpolatedScalars(1) = 5.01;
figure, showPointCloud( coord', interpolatedScalars, 'MarkerSize', 60 );
colormap(jet)
colorbar
```

This is function created for interpolation:

```
function [interpolatedScalars] = interpolateScalars( scalars, vertices)
interpolatedScalars = zeros( size(vertices,1),1 );
for vertex_id=1:size(vertices,1)
    dist_squared = sum( ((scalars(:,1:3) - repmat( vertices(vertex_id,:)',...
        1,size(scalars,1))').^2),2 );
    weightedDist = 0.0;
    for i=1:size(scalars,1)
        weightedDist = weightedDist  +  scalars(i,4) *...
        (sum(dist_squared(1:size(scalars,1)))-dist_squared(i)) /...
        ((size(scalars,1)-1)*sum(dist_squared(1:size(scalars,1))));
    end
    interpolatedScalars(vertex_id) = weightedDist;
end
end
```

This is the output I got but the color variation is not smooth enough to interpret the thickness of skin based on color:

[image: output]

Comment: By default `jet` only uses 64 colors, you can try something like `colormap(jet(1000))`

Comment: I tried this option but it is not working well. I think the interpolation in my code is not so efficient or it has some problems. Can you please suggest some method for doing 4D interpolation in which 3 columns are for xyz coodrinates and the 4th column is for color intensity which i need to interpolate.

Comment: Look into `interpn`